# C# Y coordinate is always offset

Tags: c#, offset

I'm a bit stuck with this one.

I'm writing a visual Semaphore flag signalling application, and I'm having a bit of trouble with the positioning of labels for left and right arms.

This is the code before:

```
private void leftHandDown()
    {
        display.DrawLine(penLeftArm, centXCoord, centYCoord, LHDownXCoord, LHDownYCoord);
        lblLeftHand.Top = LHDownYCoord;
        lblLeftHand.Left = LHDownXCoord;
        lblLeftHand.Show();
    }
```

And this is what it looks like:
http://i137.photobucket.com/albums/q221/omar319/sema.png (I don't have any rep to post photos on here). I have set the background to blue, as I'm also trying to pin down another problem (labels leave a white box when they change position, not sure why).

I would like the labels to appear at the end of the hands drawn by the pen (end coordinates LHDownXCoord and LHDownYCoord) but the labels are always offset by -80px on the y-axis. The Right Hand label I have added 75px to the Y axis coordinate.

Any idea what is causing the offset?

Cheers,

Omar

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the labels need to be offset by the top left coordinates of your display control

Comment: Apologies, I'm not too sure what you mean by that. Would you be able to explain please?

Comment: Sorry! I now know what you mean.
That seems to have solved it. Is there a way to set the coordinates based on the Top-Left of the display PictureBox and not the form?

Comment: Not really, since PictureBox is not a container control. You could however use a Panel, which can then contain your labels and can be drawn to.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll try and do that later on. But your suggestion has worked. The PictureBox is offset by 74 (y) and 13 (x).

Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. Little advice... don't hard-code the offset values, use the `Left` and `Top` properties of your `PictureBox`. That way, you won't have to change the values every time you put some new controls above the display area.